# CKEditor invisible with plugins

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, ckeditor

I've got a problem with **CKEditor**. I want to install on my page CKEditor with some plugins. When I install editor *without* plugins, everything is okay. But when I added the plugins, the editor becomes invisible.

ScreenShots:
[*WITHOUT PLUGINS*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogv3e.png)
[*WITH PLUGINS*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZhuG.png)

Comment: What plugins you installed? How you installed the plugins?

Comment: I installed many plugins. Examples: autosave, CKEditor Bootstrap 3 table, CodeMirror...
I installed plugins with Builder and manual (unzip to plugins, add to config.js line: config.extraPlugins = 'pluginname';)

Sry for english

Answer (score 0):

As i faced the same problem before sometime because my config.js file was not configured properly. Kindly refer the below file.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    config.language = 'en';
    config.uiColor = '#9AB8F3';
    config.toolbar = 'Full';
    config.height = 500;
    config.toolbar_Full =
    [
        { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms', items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 
        'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv',
    '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe' ] },
    '/',
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] }
    ];

config.toolbar_Basic =
[
    ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link',     'Unlink','-','About']
];
//config.removePlugins ='liststyle,tabletools,scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';
};
```